# Number of words with 8 letters using an alphabet of 3 consonants and 2 vowels with constraints

Tags: contest-math, combinatorics-on-words

A new language is developed such that it has $5$ letters $A ,B, C ,D, E$ where
A, E are called vowels while B, C, D are called consonants . The language has the following rules :a letter cannot be repeated twice in a row (e.g the sequence $BB$ is not allowed) and a vowel cannot be repeated in a row (the sequence $AE$ or $EA$ of letters is not allowed) . Find the number of all possible eight letter words which begin with a consonants.

Background info:

This is a question that came up in the third round of the $2023$ Kenya mathematics Olympiad and the best student could only score $1$ of the possible ten marks in the question. I tried various methods  but could only arrive at $20340$ as the solution by listing all possible permutations of consonants and vowels i.e (cvcvcvcv ,cccccccc and so on) and then counted the number of words for each case.I am unsure if this is even the correct answer.

Comment: Can you explain how you got to 20340?

Comment: listing all possible permutations of consonants and vowels i.e ( cvcvcvcv ,cccccccc and so on) and then counted the number of words for each case.

Comment: Use dynamic programming: make a $5$-row table listing $f(i,k)$= number of valid words with $k$ letters that end with letter $i$. Expand this table column-by-column. Then your answer is $\sum_{i=1}^5f(i,8)$

Comment: I set up two sequences, one which gives the number of words of length n, and one which gives the number of words of length n starting with a vowel, this gives a linear dynamical system. Solving it gave me the answer as 42432. I’ll try to elaborate later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recurrence approach. Let $c(n)$ be the number of legal words such that the $n$-th letter is a consonant and let $v(n)$ be the number of legal words such that the $n$-th letter is a vowel. Then the following recurrences hold (why?): for any $n\geq 1$,
$$\begin{cases}
c(n+1)=2\cdot c(n)+3\cdot v(n)\\
v(n+1)=2\cdot c(n)+0\cdot v(n)
\end{cases}$$
or in matrix form
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
c(n+1)\\v(n+1)\\
\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & 3\\
2 & 0\\
\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}
c(n)\\v(n)\\
\end{matrix}\right].$$
In our case, starting with a consonant, we have that $c(1)=3$, $v(1)=0$ and therefore
$$\begin{array}{r|cc}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ \hline
c(n)&3&6&30&96&372&1320&4872&17664\\ \hline
v(n)&0&6&12&60&192&744&2640&9744
\end{array}$$
Hence, the total number of 8 letter words is $c(8)+v(8)=17664+9744=\boxed{27408}$.

Comment: [+1] It may be good to suggest the use of a matrix description.

Comment: can you prove why the recurrence holds ? additionally after a bit of computation the result I obtained was 34920

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree! Thanks for your comment

Comment: @RobertZ: I think you mean "vowel" rather than "vocal"?

Comment: $c(n)$ and $v(n)$ and $w(n)=c(n)+v(n)$ all satisfy the recurrence $a(n)=2a(n-1)+6a(n-2)$ but with different starting values when $n=1,2$

Comment: @psmears You are right.... Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Henry Good point!

Comment: @roinujnavog The second recurrence says: if a word of $n+1$ letters ends with a vowel then this vowel can be chosen in 2 ways and the $n$-th letter has to be a consonant. Prove the first recurrence in a similar way!

Comment: @RobertZ Yeah I can see it now . thanks for the help

Comment: An advantage of a matrix-based approach here is that to compute the number of 8-letter words, we'll want to look at the $8^{\text{th}}$ power of a matrix, which we can do by squaring three times instead of by doing seven steps of a recurrence. That is, $c(8)$ and $v(8)$ are the entries in the second column of $\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\2&0\end{bmatrix}^8 = \begin{bmatrix}10&6\\4&6\end{bmatrix}^4 = \begin{bmatrix}124&96\\64&60\end{bmatrix}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is fine.  First just strings of c's v's, and separating those with v's at the end of the word and those with no v at the end.

0 v's -- $1$
1 v not ending in v -- $6$
1 v ending in v -- $1$
2 v's not ending in v -- ${5\choose 2}$
2 v's ending in v -- ${5\choose 1}$
3 v's not ending in v -- ${4\choose 3}$
3 v's ending in v -- ${4\choose 2}$
4 v's ending in v -- ${3\choose 3}$

At the start of a word and after every v there are 3 choices for c.
Otherwise, there are 2 choices for c.
There are 2 choices for v.

${7\choose 0}(3)2^7 + {6\choose 1}(3^2)(2^6) + {6\choose 0}(3)(2^7) + {5\choose 2}(3^3)(2^5) + {5\choose 1}(3^2)(2^6)+ {4\choose 3}(3^4)(2^4)+{4\choose 2}(3^3)(2^5)+{3\choose 3}(3^4)(2^4)\\
({7\choose 0}+{6\choose 0}) (3)2^7 + ({6\choose 1}+{5\choose 1}) (3^2)(2^6) + ({5\choose 2}+{4\choose 2}) (3^3)(2^5) + ({4\choose 3}+{3\choose 3}) (3^4)(2^4)\\
27408$

Answer (score 1):

The number  20340  seems to be wrong.

Algoritmically:
Build tuples of 1...5,
select first odd,
deselect any word with a pair product of 8,
select all adjacent pairs different,

In Mathematica e.g.

```
 wordlist = Sort[Tuples[Join[v = {2, 4}, c = {1, 3, 5}], 8]];
   pairs[x_] := Join[Partition[x, 2], Partition[Rest[x], 2]]

  w = Select[wordlist,
     Function[word, OddQ[First[word]] &&
          FreeQ[Times @@@ pairs[word], 8] &&
           And @@ (Unequal[#1, #2] &) @@@ pairs[word] &)];


 Length[w]
   27408

ww = StringJoin @@@ (w /. {1 -> "c", 2 -> "a", 3 -> "p", 4 -> "u",   5 -> "t"})

 Array[Symbol@ww[[RandomInteger[27408]]] &, {24}]
```

cuputpat, ctcpacpu, ctutatcu, tupcpcut, cactpupc, ptupupuc,
tacpcatc,tucupuca, tcuctcat, cucptpuc, ptptctup, ctpucpcp,
cutcuctc, tatcupac, capcptcu, tacptcap, tutatcpc, ptctucac,
tpcptutu, catacpap, tapapcpu, pcucapup, cupctact, cpatutuc

Probably, for a romanic language one should exclude more than two consonants.

Mathematically challenging: replace the selection And-product by its nested product of combination coefficients.